# JSESSIONID not received in server Android

Tags: android, cookies, server, webview, jsessionid

I am developing an Android web application. Since `cookiesyncmanager` is deprecated, I've replaced it with `cookieManager` for android SDK 32 and above.

Because of this reason, server sporadically fails to receive JSESSIONID value and receives `null`. However, JSESSIONID has a normal value in Android internal storage when the error occurs in server. Android application has no process for cookie except cookie setting in webview when it starts running.

This error occurs in SDK 32 and 33 versions only.
I've searched for this problem for recent few weeks but couldn't get a clue.